# How to obtain all messages from my channel in telegram?

Tags: php, html, telegram

Hellow everyone!
I have a channel on telegram. And I want to automatically build windows on my site. Widget gets last messages from channel on telegram. **Like a twitter** widget. Can't to find adequate manual for it

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
updates.getChannelDifference#bb32d7c0 channel:InputChannel filter:ChannelMessagesFilter pts:int limit:int = updates.ChannelDifference;
```

It will return one of these:

```
updates.channelDifferenceEmpty#3e11affb flags:# final:flags.0?true pts:int timeout:flags.1?int = updates.ChannelDifference;
updates.channelDifferenceTooLong#5e167646 flags:# final:flags.0?true pts:int timeout:flags.1?int top_message:int top_important_message:int read_inbox_max_id:int unread_count:int unread_important_count:int messages:Vector<Message> chats:Vector<Chat> users:Vector<User> = updates.ChannelDifference;
updates.channelDifference#2064674e flags:# final:flags.0?true pts:int timeout:flags.1?int new_messages:Vector<Message> other_updates:Vector<Update> chats:Vector<Chat> users:Vector<User> = updates.ChannelDifference;
```

In your Telegram Implementation, issues `updates.getChannelDifference` periodically to pull (and cache) your new channel messages.

`updates.channelDifferenceEmpty` is returned to indicates you have seen the latest messages on your channel.

You can then *stream/push* new messages to your website *panel/widget*

Comment: hi , I have an obligation to work with you, please contact me:
aminghaderi@gmail.com or telegram : @Amingh777
I am waiting for you, Thank you.

Comment: @AminGhaderi sure, no problem